# 3d Studio Max and 2+CPUs - Core limit?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, 3ds-max

I am scouting for parts to put in a new machine, and in the process, while looking at different benchmarks I stumbled upon [this benchmark](http://www.2cpu.com/contentteller.php?ct=articles&action=pages&page=118,1.html) and it got me a bit worried.

Quote form it:

> Noticably absent from this review is
>   an old-time favorite, 3ds Max. I did
>   attempt to run our custom 3ds Max
>   benchmark on both the 2009 and 2010
>   versions of the software, but the
>   application would simply not load on
>   the Westmere box with hyper-threading
>   enabled. Evidently Autodesk didn't
>   plan far enough ahead to write their
>   software for more than 16 threads.
>   Once there is an update that addresses
>   this issue, I will happily add 3ds Max
>   back into the benchmarking mix.

Since I was looking at dual hexa-core Xeons (x5650), that would put my future machine at 24 logical cores which (duh) is well over 16 cores and since I'm mostly building this for 3DS Max work, you can see how this would seriously spoil my plans. I tried looking for additional information on this potential issue, but the above article seems to be the only one who mentions it. Could anyone who has access to a >16 core machine or an in-depth knowledge about 3DS Max please confirm this ?

Thank you all in advance !

---

Edit: If you have any additional info on this like if a fix is in the making if confirmed true would also be much appreciated as it would help me plan ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the mental ray limitations – if you want to lunch 3ds max in more than 16 threads you must remove metnalray.dlz (in the `%max root%/stdplugs` directory). Unfortunately, you can only use an external render engine (like V-Ray) if you remove mental ray. If you don't rename or eliminate `metnalray.dlz`, 3ds max will not start.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, this is good news. I always use a third party rendering engine so I have no problem in switching off mentalray. I have no ways of testing this right now but it does make sense and I will accept your answer.